# Is Dwarapalaga in Shiva temples is Nataraja?

Tags: shiva, shaivism, agamas

In certain Shiva temples I have seen Nataraja posture idol as Dwarapalaga at entrace of Shiva linga sannadhi. Is it Nataraja being Dwarapalaga or is it just a posture? What Shaiva agama says about this?

Comment: Shiva is never dvarapala.

Comment: In Puranas, Skandha and Vishakha re dvarapalas of Shiva/Shakti temples and Jaya and Vijaya of Vishnu temple

Comment: A picture would be useful to decide.

Comment: @Partha have you seen nataraja posture dvarapalas of Shiva temple? Skandha, Kartikeya is to left side of Ganesh !!!

Comment: yes, inl Southi have seen their legs like Nataraja. Jaya and Vijaya also looks like Vishnu btw